# How can I pass the same connection instance in my job in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, rets

I have a different RETS credential stored in the database. We have a job running in Laravel which fetches data. Due to the long running process, we use the job for fetching data. Now for each batch data I have to call `Login()` method in PHPRET.

Some of the MLS is allowing only a single session, so my job running parallel is failing. As I can't pass MLS class object to another job as serialization of closure is not allowed.

How can I pass the same connection instance in my job? I've seen Registering Singleton class in provider.

Comment: Can you show the code

Comment: Ya sure I'll update the question